# Result from scaled chi-square difference test and AIC/BIC are inconsistent for comparison of nested models

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am trying to compare the fit of two nested multiple-group path analysis models (Models A & B).

Model A is the model that does not have any equality constraints across genders (i.e., path coefficients and correlations are freely estimated separately for males and females).

Model B differs from Model A only by placing equality constraints for genders for the path coefficients and correlations.

I am using Mplus with the MLR estimator. So, to compare these nested models, I conducted scaled chi-square difference testing using the models' loglikelihood values. The result from that test is statistically significant, which suggests the unconstrained model fits better than the constrained model.

(Chi-square  = 33.79, df = 21,  p < .05) .

I calculated  cd to be 1.015 and TRd to be 33.78 based on the following from the two models:

Model A
Number of Free Parameters                       70
Loglikelihood
H0 Value                      -15820.276
H0 Scaling Correction Factor      1.0020
for MLR
H1 Value                      -15820.276
H1 Scaling Correction Factor      1.0020
for MLR
Information Criteria
Akaike (AIC)                   31780.551
Bayesian (BIC)                 32131.462
Sample-Size Adjusted BIC       31909.125
(n* = (n + 2) / 24)

Model B
Number of Free Parameters                       49
Loglikelihood
H0 Value                      -15837.415
H0 Scaling Correction Factor      0.9966
for MLR
H1 Value                      -15820.276
H1 Scaling Correction Factor      1.0019
for MLR
Information Criteria
Akaike (AIC)                   31772.830
Bayesian (BIC)                 32018.468
Sample-Size Adjusted BIC       31862.831
(n* = (n + 2) / 24)

Although the scaled chi-square difference test says the unconstrained model fits better, the values for AIC, BIC, and sample-size adjusted BIC from the constrained model are smaller compared to their values for the unconstrained model, respectively.

In summary, the result (and following decision) using the scaled chi-square difference test is inconsistent with the result (and following decision) using AIC, BIC, and sample-size adjusted BIC.

Can someone please explain why the scaled chi-square difference test favors the model with more parameters (i.e., Model A) while the AIC, BIC, and Sample-Size adjusted BIC favor the model with fewer parameters (i.e., Model B)?

Which fit statistic(s) should I rely on and report in this situation?

Is it misplaced to use AIC, BIC, and sample-size adjusted BIC for nested multiple-group models when the goal is to freely estimate many more parameters in one model compared to the other model?
Is the penalty correction for AIC, BIC, and sample-size BIC in this context too harsh?

Which model is better to use (i.e., Model A based on the statistical test or Model B based on parsimony)?

Thank you and Regards,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain why the scaled chi-square difference test favors the model with more parameters (i.e., Model A) while the AIC, BIC, and Sample-Size adjusted BIC favor the model with fewer parameters (i.e., Model B)?

The LRT is a test statistic, information criteria are not.  The former are used to conduct null-hypothesis significance tests, testing an exact null hypothesis without adjusting for model parsimony (in terms of how many parameters are estimated).  The latter adjust for parsimony, and are used to descriptively compare models in a way that balances parsimony and fit. They are not used for the same purpose, so they cannot really contradict each other.

> Which fit statistic(s) should I rely on and report in this situation?

Report them all.

- The LRT is only "statistically significant" relative to an arbitrary *p* value.  You reported only < .05 (the actual *p* value is .038), so that must be your alpha level: a common convention but rather liberal (1 out of 20 true null hypotheses will be rejected).
- AIC is lower for the model that estimates fewer free parameters.  It is designed to select the model that is most likely to predict new data.
- BIC is also lower for the model that estimates fewer free parameters.  It is a poor approximation of a Bayes factor (making many simplifying assumptions), and asymptotically selects the true data-generating model when it is among the competitors.  When the true model is not among those considered, then its behavior is less understood.

I prefer AIC because it is about out-of-sample prediction and doesn't assume any model is a perfect representation of real data-generating processes, but it is up to you to transparently report your own values.  Here is some reading you might find helpful.

Vrieze, S. I. (2012). Model selection and psychological theory: A discussion of the differences between the Akaike information criterion (AIC) and the Bayesian information criterion (BIC). *Psychological Methods, 17*(2), 228–243. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0027127

Bollen, K. A., Harden, J. J., Ray, S., & Zavisca, J. (2014). BIC and alternative Bayesian information criteria in the selection of structural equation models. *Structural Equation Modeling, 21*(1), 1-19. https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2014.856691

Another observation:

Your scaling factor is basically 1 (within rounding to 2 decimals), so the scaling factor in each model is only making a negligible adjustment.  That implies your data do not have enough excess kurtosis to cause a problem for your *SE*s and test statistics.  If you use standard MLE, you don't need the more complex formulas for a chi-squared difference test:

https://www.statmodel.com/chidiff.shtml